# Definite guide to making Windows ICS work over WiFi (ie. share LAN internet over WiFi adapter or function as a wireless access point)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

My laptop is running Windows 7 has both a LAN adapter and a WiFi adapter. In order to turn the WiFi adapter into a wireless hotspot, I created a new ad-hoc network, and turned on ICS, assigned the network name, security mode (WPA2) and the password. However it does not work. ie. my mobile phone does not see the wireless network. Is there something I missed?

or

What should I do to turn my Windows laptop into a wireless access point (internet is on LAN adapter) and avoid having to purchase an app like Connectify.me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second Google result for "Making ICS work over WiFi":

http://www.ishanarora.com/2009/07/29/windows-7-as-a-wireless-access-point/

P.S. Most smartphones (i.e. Android) do not support ad-hoc networks.

Comment: I'm using a Nokia 640XL.